# Does MS charge SharePoint 2010 after the extended support?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, support

SharePoint 2010 is on extended support. Does Microsoft charge if we continue to use SP 2010 after extended support?

Or its just they stop giving CU`s and security updates for that product?

When a MS case raised for SP 2010 with MS premier support will there be any additional charging from MS?

Answer (score 3):

After extended support, all support for the product ceases. That includes any patch (security, hotfix, etc.) and any support via PSS. Last I looked, unlike some other product groups, the SharePoint PG does not offer any form of paid support post-extended support (unlike Windows or SQL where you can pay an exorbitant amount of money to continue receiving support).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when SharePoint product extended , MS support team will not take the case and will suggest to upgrade a higher version of SharePoint .

SharePoint 2010 extended support end date is 13/10/2010 .

More detail please refer to : https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/lifecycle

Also MS support team will not offer even you pay additional charging .